# Without Alter Command, Delete Cascade Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have to delete a product and its images. Images are in seperate table and productId is acting as foreign key.
Here is the single queries to do so.

```
string deleteImages = @"DELETE FROM [ProductsImages] WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM [Products] WHERE ProductId = @ProductId)";
string deleteProduct = @"DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE ProductId = @ProductId";
       db.ExecuteNonQuery(deleteImages);
       db.ExecuteNonQuery(deleteProduct);
```

I am not getting the way to avoid writing 2 different queries, Is there any help to delete cascade without alter command?

Comment: Why on earth does it matter whether it's one query or two?

Comment: @Arran , For learning and it can improve my coding style :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the index, you can avoid two round trips by performing multiple operations in one command:

```
string deleteStuff = @"
  DELETE FROM [ProductsImages] WHERE ProductId = @ProductId;
  DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE ProductId = @ProductId;"
db.ExecuteNonQuery(deleteStuff);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can define in the database. Just define the foreign key relationship between Products and ProductsImages as "ON DELETE CASCADE". Deleting the product will then automatically delete all associated ProductImages.

Comment: This is true, but should perhaps be treated with a *little* caution - most places I've worked at prefer the deletes to be explicit, to prevent accidental (unplanned) deletions - they'd prefer the delete to fail (FK violation) and fix the delete code. It varies between teams, though.

Comment: Yes, but look at how they are deleting from Productimages: `WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM [Products] WHERE ProductId = @ProductId`. I suggest the less they do manually in the database, the better.

Comment: Heh; I can't fault your reasoning there! (my borderline-OCD forced me to fix that when writing my answer)

Comment: And the cascade turns into a 'what a great idea, we'll turn it on for ALL our FKs'.  Then one delete later.... there goes the data.... ;)

Comment: @Twinkles! thanx and yes we can do it manually too. i did it through query for learning :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE p.*, i.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductImages i ON p.ProductId = i.ProductId
WHERE p.ProductId = @ProductId
```

**EDIT**
Not supported by SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server says: `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`; more generally - the [`DELETE` command in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) is single-table target.